# Exim does not use /etc/hosts

Tags: ubuntu, exim

I have installed `exim4`, and my `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.1.1     mycomputer
192.168.100.5 rpi.mydomain.com
```

When I run `exim -bt john@rpi.mydomain.com` to test deliverability, it says:

```
R: dnslookup for john@rpi.mydomain.com
john@rpi.mydomain.com is undeliverable
```

Why doesn't it use the `/etc/hosts` file?

Additional information:

- System: Ubuntu.
- The address in the `/etc/hosts` file is valid. I verified this using `telnet rpi.mydomain.com 25`.

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: What distro are you on?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Ubuntu.

Comment: What does your /etc/nsswitch.conf look like?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Added contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to the question.

Comment: Do you have a firewall between you and the host, or on your client computer?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Yes, but as I said, telnet on port 25 works. I have a feeling that this issue is specific to Ubuntu. I'll try to ask elsewhere.

Comment: Exim uses port 465 by default.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096080/exim-use-etc-hosts-to-resolve-domain-names

Comment: The reason is very simple: `hosts` file is **not** dns.

Comment: Expected behaviour, it does not use hosts

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this part of Exim documentation.](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_dnslookup_router.html)

In short, email delivery relies pretty heavily on `MX` records of the DNS system, and there is no equivalent for them in `/etc/hosts`.

Apparently Exim's test feature first takes into account whether Exim is configured to use a smarthost or not; if it has, it would report the address(es) of the smarthost it knows about. (Smarthost configuration = old `sendmail`-based email terminology meaning "don't attempt to deliver directly to destination address - instead, send all outgoing email to one specific server for further processing.")

If no smarthost configuration is in use, the test checks for the presence of a DNS `MX` record for `rpi.mydomain.com`. If the MX record is of the following form, it is interpreted to mean explicitly "no email service for this domain" and the search ends:

```
rpi.mydomain.com. IN MX 0 .
```

If there is no MX record in DNS and `rpi.mydomain.com` is listed in Exim configuration item `mx_domains`, the search will also end with a "mail is undeliverable" error.

If the above did not already terminate the search, Exim will check for `A` or `AAAA` records in the DNS.

In your own network, if you wish to use `rpi.mydomain.com` as your mail server, you should configure your local Exim to use it as a smarthost. [Here's the relevant bit of Exim documentation.](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-some_common_configuration_settings.html) In short, replace the default `dnslookup` mail router configuration block with this Exim configuration block:

```
send_to_smart_host:
  driver = manualroute
  route_list = !+local_domains rpi.mydomain.com
  transport = remote_smtp
```

This should cause all mail whose destination is not the local inbox `/var/mail/<username>` to be sent to `rpi.mydomain.com` for further processing.

Well-behaving mail servers have long been expected to have a valid DNS registration, and also a valid reverse DNS registration that is in agreement with the forward DNS record.

Generally, when a mail server receives an incoming connection that is not authenticated and does not come from a known-trusted network, the mail server will typically first make a reverse DNS lookup to find out the name of the system trying to connect. Then it makes a forward DNS lookup using that name, and compares the resulting IP address(es) to the actual source IP of the connection. If there is no match, or there is no reverse DNS record, the connection is assumed to come from a possible spammer and can be subjected to stricter checks or outright disconnected. This is one of the oldest anti-spam checks.

Comment: The answer is quite good, I think you could mention the possibility of adding some DNS dual view setup to complete it. +1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: feel free to edit it in. I tried to restrict myself to a description of SMTP's dependency on DNS and practical advice for the asker, and already deleted one chapter's worth of getting sidetracked before posting.

Comment: It is you answer, so I trust your judgement.